# Make Window pop Up when Creating a document template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to make a small pop up window that allows user to enter metadata when creating a new document from a document template. Please how do I go about this? I'm open to other work around too.[image]

PS: I don't have designer

Answer (score 0):

Add script Editor web-part on page and add below script in it.

Note: Just replace `button id` and `page url`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#YourDocTemplateButtonID").click(function(){
        openDialog();
    });
    });

    function openDialog() {  
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(   
         {  
           url: "page url that you want to open in pop-up",
           width: 500,  
           height: 500,  
           title: "Dialog Title"  
         }  
      );  
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please where can i get the button from ?

Comment: Currently on which event your form is opening?

Comment: When you want to open this page? means after clicking on any button,any link or else?

Comment: Right now I have an excel form that opens when I click on the green button in the image.   I want the dialog box in the image to come up first when th ebutton is clicked and then the excel form should come up after the save button on the dialog box has been clicked

Comment: The green button is a webpart I created.

Comment: So you dont know that button id?

Comment: Where should I put the document id in the code you posted?